# How to read from a file and store the data to a structure and calculate formula?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I have a file named `test.txt` with following data

`2
Salman Khan
20 100000 4.75 1000
Aamir khan
30 200000 5.25 1000`

where 
the first line is the number of user records,
the second line is Name separated by space, and
the third line consists of years, amount, rate, amount per month that the user is qualified.

I want to calculate formula and show into a table.

so far i've done is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Customers
{
    char first_name[50];
    char last_name[30];
    int years; 
    float amount; 
    float interest_rate;
    float amount_per_month;
}; 

int main() {
    Customers cus;

    int sum = 0;
    string x,line;
    string fileName = "";
    ifstream inFile;

    string firstLine;
    int numberOfCustomers = 0;

    cout << "Enter File Name: \n";
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << "Reading File : '"+ fileName+"'" << endl;

    inFile.open(fileName);
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    if (inFile.good())
      {
        getline(inFile, firstLine);
        numberOfCustomers = stoi(firstLine);
        cout << "Available Loan Applications : " << numberOfCustomers << endl;
      }

     while (inFile >> x) {
       cout << x << endl;
       cin >> cus.first_name;
    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to store data to structure and then calculate, i need help in storing data to structure.

Comment: @Ruks The accepted answer, on the question that you linked, invokes undefined behavior, due to writing/reading of non-POD types via `std::istream::read`/`std::ostream::write`. Don't suggest relying on some behavior of undefined behavior. Yes, I understand that there are answers there, that doesn't invoke UB, but typical user would go after the accepted answer first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stream extraction and stream insertion operators to read/write custom datatypes:

```
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t
#include <cstdlib>   // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <iterator>  // std::istream_iterator<>
#include <vector>    // std::vector<>
#include <string>    // std::string
#include <fstream>   // std::ifstream
#include <iostream>  // std::cout, std::cerr, std::ostream, std::istream

using namespace std;

struct Customer {
    string first_name, last_name;
    int years;
    float amount, interest_rate, amount_per_month;
};

// define a stream extraction operator that takes a Customer on the right hand side
// usage examples: std::cin >> customer;
//                 file >> customer;
istream& operator>>(istream &is, Customer &customer)
{
    // don't write directly into the members of Customer to not leave
    // the object in a flunky state if extraction fails for some value.
    string first_name, last_name;
    int years;
    float amount, interest_rate, amount_per_month;

    if (!(is >> first_name >> last_name >> years >> amount >> interest_rate >> amount_per_month))
        return is;  // if extraction of a value fails end here

    // if we reach here all values have been read successfully and can be
    // assigned to the customer:
    customer = { first_name, last_name, years, amount, interest_rate, amount_per_month };
    return is;
}

// define a stream insertion operator that takes a Customer on the right hand side
// usage examples: std::cout << customer;
//                 file << customer;
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Customer const &customer)
{
    os << customer.first_name << ' ' << customer.last_name << '\n' << customer.years << ' ' 
       << customer.amount << ' ' << customer.interest_rate << ' ' << customer.amount_per_month;

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    string fileName;
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream inFile{ fileName };  // define variables as close to where they're
                                  // used. Use the constructor where app-
                                  // ropriate - here to open the file.
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {      // if the file couldn't be opened
        cerr << "Unable to open \"" << fileName << "\" for reading!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;      // exit main() returning a value that
    }                             // indicates an error

    cout << "Reading file \"" + fileName + "\":\n";

    size_t numCustomers;
    if (!(inFile >> numCustomers)) {  // read the number of customers before-
                                      // hand since this value is not part of
                                      // a customer record.
        cerr << "Couldn't read number of customers from \"" << fileName << "\"!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // use an istream_iterator that will use our stream extraction operator
    // to read customers from inFile until it reaches EOF or an error occurs.
    vector<Customer> Customers{ istream_iterator<Customer>{ inFile },
                                istream_iterator<Customer>{} };

    if (numCustomers != Customers.size()) {  // check if the number of customers
                                             // specified in the file matches
                                             // the number of customers we
                                             // were able to extract.
        cerr << "Number of customers specified in \"" << fileName
             << "\" does not match the number of customers read!\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;  // if the numbers don't match there was an error
    }                         // while reading the records from the file

    for (auto const &c : Customers)  // just to check print the customers
        std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

#### Output:

```
Enter File Name: test.txt
Reading file "test.txt":
Salman Khan
20 100000 4.75 1000
Aamir khan
30 200000 5.25 1000
```

Comment: The answer will be better if you add comments explaining what you did -- either as  comments in the code or as description outside the code.